# Simple C++ smart buffer that contains `unique_ptr`

Tags: c++

I designed this smart buffer. I'd use `std::vector` but I don't want to copy things, I want to use a ready buffer and I want it to be self deleted when `Buffer` gets deleted.

```
struct Buffer
    {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<uint8_t *> data;
        size_t len = 0;
        Buffer(CBuffer cBuffer)
        {
            data = std::make_unique<uint8_t *>(cBuffer.data);
            len = cBuffer.len;
        }
        Buffer(bool empty)
        {
            data = std::make_unique<uint8_t *>(nullptr);
            this->len = 0;
        }
        bool empty = false;
    };
```

The problem with this buffer is that I get errors like this:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'unsigned char *const *' with an lvalue of type 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *')
                auto b = return_something(raw_buffer, buffer.len);
```

in

```
uint8_t* raw_buffer = *buffer.data;
auto b = return_something(raw_buffer, buffer.len);
```

What is `unsigned char *const *`? And will this `Buffer` work and delete the managed buffer on destruction?

Comment: The error suggests that `return_something` does not take a parameter of type `uint8_t*`, which is what you are trying to pass to it. Show a [mcve], or at the very least the declaration of the function the error message actually complains about. You are showing a class that doesn't appear to have anything to do with the error message.

Comment: `Buffer` doesn't manage any buffer. It manages a single `uint8_t*` pointer (it's unclear why you feel the need to allocate that on the heap, but yes, it'll deallocate that pointer in its destructor).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to manage an `uint8_t` buffer, not exactly a pointer to `uint8_t`, that's why I need it on the heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::vector` as it clears memory by itself upon scope end. Use smart pointers, when standard containers are not possible.

Specific to your problem. The smart pointer has to be declared without `*`:

`std::unique_ptr<X>` (not X*)

Comment: If I do that, then in the destruction wouldn't it delete only the value of the pointer?

Comment: @Guerlando, upon the scope end, while destruction, the pointer [address] is deleted. Not the [indirected] pointer value.

Comment: How should I construct this buffer? Compiler is complaining about me being not able to initialize `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>(buffer.data)` where `buffer.data` is of type `uint8_t*`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, from your above query, I realise that what are you trying to achieve. You may refer the link duplicate post for the same. In a nutshell, if you don't want to use `std::vector<X>` or `std::string` etc, then use `std::unique_ptr<X[]>`.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>` but it didn't work. Then I simply did `data = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` and it worked. However I don't know how to get the raw pointer `uint8_t*` for me to write inside. On the suggested answer there's nothing about this

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, you may use the [`unique_ptr::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/get/) method which provides the underlying pointer.